# Inline Assembly Stack Behavior

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, stack

I'm trying to integrate my assembly code into c programs to make it easier to access. 
  I try to run the following code (I'm on an x64 64 bit architecture)

```
 void push(long address) {
      __asm__ __volatile__("movq %0, %%rax;"
                            "push %%rax"::"r"(address));
 }
```

The value of $rsp doesn't seem to change (neither does esp for that matter). Am I missing something obvious about how constraints work? rax is getting correctly allocated with address, but address never seems to get pushed onto the stack?

Comment: I'm guessing the compiler generates a prolog and epilog for your function which saves and restores the stack pointer. You probably need to mark it [`naked`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that.

Inline asm must document to the compiler the inputs it takes, the outputs it produces, and any other state it clobbers as part of its execution. Yours fails to do so, but perhaps more to the point, there is no way you could possibly be allowed to clobber the stack pointer like you're doing, since the surrounding code, when it regains control after the asm block, would have no way to find any of its data - even if it had saved it on the stack knowing it would be clobbered, it would have no way to get it back.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but whatever it is, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: When you say clobbering, that means that in this case, i should write rax,rsp as being clobbered? (assuming that I'm fine with my program segfaulting for now. I just want to understand the behaviour. My understanding was that the asm block was not a function, so that there was no stack frame or return address. )

Comment: As I said there is absolutely no way to do what you're trying to do. Even if you could indicate that you were going to clobber the stack pointer, the surrounding code would have no way to continue with it trashed. And if it did have a way to recover it, it would undo the action you're trying to perform.

Comment: I think your confusion is assuming that you can factor a single push as a function (or even an inline asm statement). Instead, for whatever purpose you're pushing data onto the stack for, you need to do the whole operation in one single asm block where stack adjustments are balanced so that the end of the block, the stack pointer is exactly where it was when you started.

Comment: Makes sense, I was doing it in multiple blocks (and then jumping).